# Can somebody help improve this code for counting vowels in a string

Tags: java, string, counter

I need a code that counts the vowels in a given string, i can create the code that counts the vowels but the problem is that i can't build a code that will count the vowels till the end of the string , so far i have created this code , and i have to give everytime word.charAt(index) beacuse i cannot know how long the given word will be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Give a word: ");
    String word = scan.nextLine();
    int aCounter = 0;
    int eCounter = 0;
    int iCounter = 0;
    int oCounter = 0;
    int uCounter = 0;
    int yCounter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i <= word.length(); i++){
    switch(word.charAt(0)){
    case 'a': aCounter++; break;
    case 'e': eCounter++; break;
    case 'i': iCounter++; break;
    case 'o': oCounter++; break;
    case 'u': uCounter++; break;
    case 'y': yCounter++; break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Letter not found");
    }
    switch(word.charAt(1)){
        case 'a': aCounter++; break;
        case 'e': eCounter++; break;
        case 'i': iCounter++; break;
        case 'o': oCounter++; break;
        case 'u': uCounter++; break;
        case 'y': yCounter++; break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Letter not found");
        }

    }


    if (aCounter > 0) System.out.println("In the given word " + word + " are " + aCounter + " a");
    if (eCounter > 0) System.out.println("In the given word " + word + " are " + eCounter + " e");
    if (iCounter > 0) System.out.println("In the given word " + word + " are " + iCounter + " i");
    if (oCounter > 0) System.out.println("In the given word " + word + " are " + oCounter + " o");
    if (uCounter > 0) System.out.println("In the given word " + word + " are " + uCounter + " u");
    if (yCounter > 0) System.out.println("In the given word " + word + " are " + yCounter + " y");










}
```

}

Comment: In what way does the code currently not work?

Comment: the code works fine but let's say the user gives the word ''hello'' and the code will only count two first letter ''he'' and it will say that there are only one ''e'' , it won't count till the end of the word , i need a code that will count all vowels till the end of the given word , thank you.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Comment: @Remmargrop No offence, but it sounds like you should read some more of your favourite Java book/tutorial.

Comment: @Remmargrop: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

Simply use word.charAt(i) in your for loop.

Moreover, consider using a Map to count the letters.